# Activeadmin has_many form for show and edit only

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, polymorphism

First please note that i am working with rails 4 and activeadmin rails 4 branch. https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/tree/rails4

I have two models pictue which is ploymorphic

```rb
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :picture_category
 belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

 mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

And ship

```rb
class Ship < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures
end
```

And activeadmin ship.rb

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Ship do

   form do |f|
      f.inputs do
      f.inputs
        f.has_many :pictures, :sortable => :picture_categories do |ff|
          ff.input :name
        end
      end
   f.actions
   end

 controller do
   def permitted_params
     params.permit(:ship => [:name, :title, :short_desc, :description, :position, :pictures, :enabled, :ship_provider_id, :picture_category_id, :picture_id])
   end
 end
end
```

but the result is this:

[image]

1. How can get rid of delete button and have submit
2. how can i show this form only on show and edit form because thats not make sense having child before parents

Please point what are mistakes in code.

Comment: I just noticed this line should also have f.actions but still dosent submit form         

f.has_many :pictures, :sortable => :picture_categories do |ff|
          ff.input :name
        end

Answer (score 0):

I know how make a solve a first problem/
You need insert **:submit** action instead button for your nested resource input. Example:

```
form do |ship|
  ship.inputs t(:ship_details) do
    ship.input :name, :label => t(:name)
    ship.input :description, :label => t(:description)
    ship.has_many :pictures do |picture|
      picture.input :url
      picture.input :imgdescription
      picture.actions do
        picture.action :submit
      end
    end
  end
end
```